# Is there a software or application that can be used to create an appointment scheduling system with rule sets?

Tags: calendar, scheduling

I have been scouring the web looking for appointment scheduling software or an application that can be used to create an appointment scheduling system.

What I am looking for is an appointment system that has rule sets that are highly customizable. I work in a department that handles truck loading/unloading and I am trying to find a better appointment scheduling system than what we currently use which is Microsoft Outlook calendar.

For example: We have a variety of service types (top picks, forklift moves, billets & blackbar, etc.) Our operation can only handle a certain number of certain service types at the same time. Theoretically speaking, let's say we have 3 trucks looking to schedule during the 8am hour on a particular day. All 3 trucks are top pick freight. Myself and another team member have already scheduled 2 of those top picks trucks for the 8am hour. A third team member then schedules the third top pick truck for the 8am hour. In this situation, we would have over-booked ourselves with top picks for the 8am hour.

What I am looking for is a means of systematically preventing any team member from over-scheduling certain service types.

Can something like this be created in Microsoft Excel? Or perhaps another program?

I have no experience with coding or programing, but regardless I am open to any and all suggestions. I can potentially outsource someone who could assist with those things. I should also add that I am looking for a free or low-cost means of accomplishing what I have described above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been looking into this for weeks and have had zero luck.

Can something like this be created in Microsoft Excel? Or perhaps another program?

I have no experience with coding or programing, but regardless I am open to any and all suggestions. I can potentially outsource someone who could assist with those things.

I should also add that I am looking for a free or low-cost means of accomplishing what I have described above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have been looking into this for weeks and have had zero luck.